# How to calculate the change in momentum of a fluid-particle system?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, momentum

Suppose I have a closed tank filled with water and a solid sphere sedimenting (under gravity) at terminal velocity inside this tank. For example a marble in an aquarium.

I know the drag force exerted by the fluid on the particle must equal the gravitational force. By Newton's third law the fluid must experience an equal and opposite force. Is it possible in this case to calculate the time rate of change in momentum analytically?

To me the integral form of the (incompressible) Navier-Stokes equations seems like a reasonable starting point. Because there is no momentum flux over the tank boundaries I believe those (taking the whole tank as a control volume) can be written as:

$\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\int_V \rho\vec{u}dV = \vec{F}_{sphere} + \int_S \vec{t}dS$

Where $F_{sphere}$ is the (known) force by the sphere on the fluid and $\int_s \vec{t}dS$ is the (unknown) integral of stresses over the tank walls. Is there a reasonable assumption I am missing which would let me calculate $\int_s\vec{t}dS$ and thus the rate of change of momentum?

Comment: If the sphere is at terminal velocity, then the rate of change of sphere momentum and fluid momentum are both zero.

Comment: Could you explain your comment? I agree that the rate of change of sphere momentum is zero. However if I see the sphere and the water in the tank as one system then there are two forces acting on it: the gravitational force on the sphere and the force exerted by the tank walls. Your conclusion would hold if these two are equal but opposite, but I don't see why this is necessarily the case.

Comment: The gravitational force on the sphere is included in the force balance on the sphere, including the buoyancy effect.  The force exerted by the tank walls and bottom matches this.

Comment: Could you explain why your statement that the force exerted by tank bottom and walls is true?